# How to change table to different style at same page

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to use this table style at same page with another one, but always other one control this one, so please can you change this for me to become different style. Please would you mind to make it with a Jsfiddle example.

Here my CSS:

```
body {
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}
table {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 7px;
}
table > thead > tr > th,
table > tbody > tr > th,
table > tfoot > tr > th,
table > thead > tr > td,
table > tbody > tr > td,
table > tfoot > tr > td {
  padding: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
table th {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #868686;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 0 13px !important;
}
table td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all .2s ease;
  font-size: 13px;
}
table td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
table td:first-child {
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
table > thead > tr > th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
table > caption + thead > tr:first-child > th,
table > colgroup + thead > tr:first-child > th,
table > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > th,
table > caption + thead > tr:first-child > td,
table > colgroup + thead > tr:first-child > td,
table > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > td {
  border: 0;
}
table > tbody > tr:hover > td,
table > tbody > tr:hover > th {
  background-color: #f7f8fb;
}
```

Here my HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="20">1</td>
      <td>Obcasyn Maruszczak</td>
      <td>obcasyn@example.com</td>
      <td>No comment</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Obcasyn Maruszczakowy</td>
      <td>maruszczak@example.com</td>
      <td>No comment</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Obcasyn Maruszczakowy</td>
      <td>maruszczak@example.com</td>
      <td>No comment</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give them the same class (say `"tables"`) and different ids (say `"tableOne"` and `"tableTwo"`)

Declare the common css for them using their class, like `table.tables{ }`. For  different css use their ids; like  this :

```
table.tables#tableOne th {
  color:green;
}
table.tables#tableTwo th {
  color: red;
}
```

Here's a wokring snippet in which I give their headings different colors using their ids.

```css
body {
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}
table.tables {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 7px;
}
table.tables > thead > tr > th,
table.tables > tbody > tr > th,
table.tables > tfoot > tr > th,
table.tables > thead > tr > td,
table.tables > tbody > tr > td,
table.tables > tfoot > tr > td {
  padding: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
table.tables th {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #868686;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 0 13px !important;
}
table.tables td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all .2s ease;
  font-size: 13px;
}
table.tables td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
table.tables td:first-child {
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
table.tables > thead > tr > th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
table.tables > caption + thead > tr:first-child > th,
table.tables > colgroup + thead > tr:first-child > th,
table.tables > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > th,
table.tables > caption + thead > tr:first-child > td,
table.tables > colgroup + thead > tr:first-child > td,
table.tables > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > td {
  border: 0;
}
table.tables > tbody > tr:hover > td,
table.tables > tbody > tr:hover > th {
  background-color: #f7f8fb;
}

table.tables#tableOne th {
  color:green;
}
table.tables#tableTwo th {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="tables" id="tableOne">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="20">1</td>
      <td>Obcasyn Maruszczak</td>
      <td>obcasyn@example.com</td>
      <td>No comment</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="tables" id="tableTwo">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="20">1</td>
      <td>Obcasyn Maruszczak</td>
      <td>obcasyn@example.com</td>
      <td>No comment</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Car ..it work perfect thank you , but i have new problem , when i use them them becomes like this style http://www.up-9.com/uploads/148445292904681.jpg

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that . can you add a screenshot of the result and set up a fiddle for the relevant code.

Comment: Ok. I got the screenshot can you set up a fiddle or the relevant code that replicates your problem and are you using bootstrap?

Comment: you can fix the width for the first column like this  `table>tbody>tr>td:first-child{width:120px;}` Here's the updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tv8bqbn6/2/  the only change is in the css (at the very last)

Comment: you have to insert it in a media query otherwise in the small screen the team name wont cover full screen.

Comment: kitty Cat ,,thank you ,if i have to face problem i will confirm here ,i try right now to test